# Parameter resolving /converter for dynamically registered commands

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, spring-shell

I am working on a Spring Shell 2 CLI and i am trying to generate commands at runtime from a defined interface through reflection. 
**Update: The implementation of the interface is also generated at runtime.**

I am using the ConfigurableCommandRegistry and MethodTarget to register my command.
Is there a way to setup/register converters at runtime for the parameters of the method that is passed to MethodTarget? 
What would be the best approach to do this?

I am pretty new to java and spring and i am not sure if this is possible at all. Keep that in mind and pls dont kill me :)
 
The [Extending Spring Shell](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#extending-spring-shell) of the docs is missing (incomplete?)
I already checked the [Spring shell project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell) but could not find something to work with.
Maybe this is possible with Parameter Resolving?
or generating Converters at runtime with FormatterRegistrar?

Registering commands as followed

```
MethodTarget command = new MethodTarget(method, client, new Command.Help(description, group), availabilityIndicator);
registry.register(commandName, command);
```

method and method paramters, client, description, group is retrieved via reflection from the interface.

I would like to generate a command at runtime from an interface

```
public interface MessagingManagement {
  @ShellMethod(...)
  public void createPerson(@ShellOption(...)Person person);
}
```

which is callable with following parameters
create-person --person name age  (or more paramters)

In short i would like to generate converters for paramaters that are complex objects and flatten them.
Nested objects are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Any bean that is a `Converter<String, Person>` should work and be picked up by Spring Shell automatically. Have a look at [ConversionExample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell/blob/5ec589909ed320f999ade109dcc97087e072893b/spring-shell-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/shell/samples/standard/ConversionExample.java) in the samples.

That being said, why are you saying you want to register everything ***dynamically***? Spring Shell is meant to pick up code annotated with its special annotations (like eg `@ShellMethod`). While it should be possible to dynamically do the work that the standard registrars do when seeing those annotations, it seems from your examples that you're OK with annotating your code with `@ShellMethod` already? So why not let Spring Shell do the discovery and registration for you?

To put it another way: why are you annotating the interface rather that the implementation method? If you did so, you wouldn't have to deal with `MethodTarget` etc, this is all done automatically for you by Spring Shell.

Hopefully this clarifies things and turns out to be the simplest solution

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Actually the implemenation of the service is generated at runtime. I forgott to mention this importent information in my initial question, sry!

Comment: How is it generated? Can the generated *implementation* bear the Spring Shell annotations (instead of the interface)?

Comment: When a Converter e.g. Converter<String, Person> is used e.g.
`public class Person {
private String name;
private String addresse;
private int age;
}`
I loose the detailed information of the pojo, including the available parameters, their type wether they are mandatory or not, etc.
To put it different. When i use a converter is it possible to pass single parameters by name like:"add-person --name foo --address bar --age 42"
or do i have to input the person parameters e.g. as json
"add-person {name:foo, address:bar, age:42 }" Without any input help for the single parameters of the pojo?